# how to disable fbcon?

Tags: kernel, console

my boot have several systems fighting for fb control. kms, amdgpu, systemd-boot, efi, fbcon...

it's a mess. my resolution and font keeps changing during boot. Not just changing, but changing back and forth! I care about that because it messes up the moment i have to type in the password for cryptsetup.

```
$ dmesg | grep fb0
[    0.496628] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    2.357990] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.451584] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
```

what happens:

```
efi (1920x1200)
  -> fbcon (less than 1920x1200, fonts from vconsole.conf)
    -> kms (1920x1200, reset fonts)
```

EFI vga and admgpu (kms?) use the correct resolution. fbcon doesn't. Is there anyway to kill it completely?

i don't see any way to turn it off, OR set the correct mode: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/fbcon.html

using `nomodeset` kernel option is not an option. as `amdgpu` requires it.

tried to set `video=efifb` to make fbcon use the efi resolution, but no lucky, it changes it just the same.

a workaround that somewhat works but still happens after 2s is to force the vconsole.conf fonts and the right resolution on kernel options.
`fbcon=font:iso01-12x22 fbcon=nodefer video=eDP-1:1920x1200@60.03`